# Why is my small program crashing?

Tags: c, char, atoi

I'm trying to make a tiny program where you input for example 1 + 2 and the output should be the sum of those two numbers. But it keeps crashing and or won't do anything. What's going on?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

char *op;
char *first;
char *second;

printf("Enter operation\n");
scanf(" %s%s%s", &first, &op, &second);

int num1;
int num2;
int num3;
int add;

num1 = atoi(first);
num2 = atoi(op);
num3 = atoi(second);

add = num1 + num3;


printf("Sum = %i\n",add);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post full compile output. Read: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/  and some good book about C

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/RKj9B1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atoi` takes argument as `const char *` and not `char` . Your variables are of type `char` where as `atoi` converts string to `int` type.

Also you pass `char *` as argument to `%d` in `scanf` , that results in undefined behavour.

```
scanf(" %d%d%d", &first, &op, &second)
        ^^^^^^ expects int * not char *
```